# Should I use QScopedPointer or std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, c++14

I'm starting a new project, using Qt5 and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++1y`.  I'm not sure whether I should prefer `QScopedPointer` or `std::unique_ptr`.

I read [somewhere](/q/25786778) that `QScopedPointer` is not that cool any more.

Does `QScopedPointer` have any features `unique_ptr` lacks?  Are there any features of `unique_ptr` that I wouldn't want in when replacing `QScopedPointer`?  Or vice versa?

Comment: I would use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: I can say I have reduced my usage of Qt smart pointers and have moved to using `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: Whenever I have a choice between a class from the standard library and a different one, I always choose the standard library unless there's a compelling reason. One such compelling reason would be if you need interoperability with code that uses the other type.

Comment: I added some objective questions along the lines of what would help make the decision.  So instead of just an opinion, it now asks for features that one lacks and the other has.

Comment: "I read somewhere that QScopedPointer is not that cool any more." That "somewhere" is effectively a dupe of this question. Sigh.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`QScopedPointer` is strictly weaker than `unique_ptr` as it does not support move semantics.

Its functionality is otherwise extremely similar.

Move semantics are extremely useful, and accidentally using them incorrectly to cause problems is extremely rare.  So they vary from harmless to (more typically) helpful.

About the only reason you should use `QScopedPointer` is interoperability with existing code bases; and even there, given how similar they are, an adapter would be pretty easy.

So if you don't need to adapt, use `unique_ptr`.

---

I will now discuss adapting.

The tricky part is the 2nd parameter to `QScopedPointer`.  It very roughly corresponds to the 2nd parameter of `unique_ptr`.

In `unique_ptr` stateful deleters are permitted.  In `QScopedPointer` they are not.  The

```
static void cleanup(T* pointer)
```

corresponds to the

```
void operator()(T* pointer)const
```

in the `unique_ptr` in a pretty one-to-one basis.  So:

```
template<class QDelete>
struct std_deleter {
  template<class T>
  void operator()(T* target) const {
    QDelete::cleanup(target);
  }
};
```

maps a Qt deleter to a std deleter.  The other way is limited by the deleter being stateless:

```
template<class Std_deleter>
struct Qt_deleter {
  template<class T>
  static void cleanup(T* target) {
    static_assert(std::is_empty<Std_deleter>{}, "Only works with stateless deleters");
    Std_deleter{}(target);
  }
};
```

we can now convert:

```
template<class T, class D>
QScopedPointer<T, Qt_deleter<D>>
to_qt( std::unique_ptr<T, D>&& src ) {
  return src.release();
}
template<class T, class D>
QScopedPointer<T, Qt_deleter<D>>
to_qt( std::unique_ptr<T[], D>&& src ) {
  return src.release();
}
template<class T>
QScopedPointer<T>
to_qt( std::unique_ptr<T>&& src ) {
  return src.release();
}
template<class T>
QScopedPointer<T, QScopedPointerArrayDeleter>
to_qt( std::unique_ptr<T[]>&& src ) {
  return src.release();
}
template<
  class T, class D, class R=std::unique_ptr<T, std_deleter<D> >
>
to_std( QScopedPointer<T, D>&& src ) {
  return R(src.take()); // must be explicit
}
template<class T, class R=std::unique_ptr<T>>
to_std( QScopedPointer<T>&& src ) {
  return R(src.take()); // must be explicit
}
template<class T, class R=std::unique_ptr<T[]>>
to_std( QScopedPointer<T,QScopedPointerArrayDeleter >&& src ) {
  return R(src.take()); // must be explicit
}
```

which covers about the only reason why you'd use `QScopedPointer`.  There are a few corner cases -- the default deleter `QScopedPointer` should be converted to a default `std::unique_ptr` and vice versa.

The array delete `QScopedPointer` should be converted to a `unique_ptr<T[]>` and vice versa.

In other cases, I simply wrap up the deleter.  In theory, a really fancy trick would be to notice if the incoming deleter was already wrapped up and reverse the wrapping, but if your code is doing that many round-trips there is probably already something wrong.

Comment: "interoperability with existing code bases" I wouldn't call it "interoperability". `QScopedPointer` is really meant for C++98 code bases (which is why `QScopedPointer` doesn't have move semantics). Given you can't even move it, it's typically just an implementation aid, and you don't see it exposed in any APIs (unlike `unique_ptr`). And the Qt project is deliberately not making `QScopedPointer` any better -- you've already got that, it's `unique_ptr`. Use `unique_ptr`, not `QScopedPointer`, in new, C++11-enabled projects.

Comment: @peppe imagine a 10 million line code base that "returns" QScopedPointer via reference and takes parameters via QScopedPointer ref and cref all over the place, some of it legacy libraries you no longer have source for but must preserve functionality, and temble.  My point is, even if you have that blasted hellscape of an existing code base, don't use QScopedPointer.  Use `to_qt` and `to_std`.

Comment: @drumm "Changing resolution: this feature was removed." "Out of Scope" -- naive read is that this was not done?

Comment: @Yakk, yes indeed. Probably because of what peppe is saying. one more reason not to use QScopedPointer once again. I can also not use the make_unique because of compiler restrictions but of a good thing Qt is adapting to the standard. It’s just stupid that e.g. QSharedPointer has move semantics, but I guess it’s also better to use sharedpointer.

Comment: What does it mean `QScopedPointer does not support move semantics`? It doesn't have move constructor and move assignment operator?

Comment: @KcFnMi https://interest.qt-project.narkive.com/fWYzJaN9/qscopedpointer-and-c-11-move-semantics it may have changed, but no, it doesn't support move constructor nor move assignment in at least the last version I personally checked.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you use something that's not from the standard library compared to something from the standard library?

To me there's only one reason any good programmer would do that: If the external library provides something that the standard library doesn't provide. Is that the case?

Consider your program's portability and updates in the future, and then make that decision.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the main intention of both classes is similar,one important difference between those two which makes you to take some business decision.

**QScopedPointer does not have an assignment operator. Where as std::unique_ptr has assignment operator.**

If you want to be strict on your QT object/control and does not want an assignment use QScopedPointer.

Comment: `const unique_ptr` also does not have an assignment operator.

Comment: Yep. But OP did not say const.