# Qt smart pointers compatability with std smart pointers

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers

In Qt I am using `QSharedPointer` and `QScopedPointer` in a way I would use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`.

For the `QSharedPointer`, I find it to be very compatible with its `std` equivalent. It has move semantics and I can use `std::make_shared()`-like functionality via a static `create()` method.

For the `QScopedPointer`, however, I find it lacking its `std` equivalent features. I know for sure I cannot move it to `QScopedPointer`, and now I am wondering why there is also no `std::make_unique()`-like functionality? Am I missing something? If no, is there a better way to get `std::unique_ptr` functionality within Qt (of course, apart from using `std::unique_ptr` itself)?

Comment: you may find this usefull [Should I use QScopedPointer or std::unique_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346393/should-i-use-qscopedpointer-or-stdunique-ptr)

Comment: just use `unique_ptr`, as its not used in the `Qt` API due to its non movability.